# Syntax error when using find_elements_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, syntax

Web scraping beginner here.
I am trying to get the amount of items on this webpage: https://www.asos.com/dk/maend/a-to-z-of-brands/nike/cat/?cid=4766&refine=attribute_10992:61388&nlid=mw|sko|shop+efter+brand

However when I use the len()-function, it says there is an error in the syntax.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox


driver = Firefox()

url = "https://www.asos.com/dk/maend/a-to-z-of-brands/nike/cat/?cid=4766&refine=attribute_10992:61388&nlid=mw|sko|shop+efter+brand"
driver.get(url)

items = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="product-12257648"])

for item in range(items):
    price = item.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div/article[16]/a/p/span[1]")
    print(price)
```

It then outputs this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/rasmu/PycharmProjects/du nu ffs/jsscrape.py", line 13
    items = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="product-12257648"])
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
items = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-12257648']"))
```

You need double quotes surrounding the XPath.

If you want all prices, you can refactor your code as such --

```
from selenium import webdriver

# start driver, navigate to url
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.asos.com/dk/maend/a-to-z-of-brands/nike/cat/?cid=4766&refine=attribute_10992:61388&nlid=mw|sko|shop+efter+brand"
driver.get(url)

# iterate product price elements
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[./span[@data-auto-id='productTilePrice']]"):

    # print price text of element
    print(item.text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: This definitely solved the problem. However I would like to know how to get to that xpath? When I copy the xpath from the source code-viewer thing in firefox for the price-element, it gives me this xpath:

`/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/article[1]/a/p/span`

Comment: @rasmusschaal open inspect element, then pess Ctrl + f and paste your xpath, to check if everything is ok. I think this can help you https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp